# Get HD Netflix videos on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, hd-video, netflix

Netflix works great on virtualbox, however it doesn't show up with any options for HD viewing. I have installed Guest Additions, any way to get the HD option to show up?

E.G. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAfRc.png Normally Futurama has an HD button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is specifically locked on movie studios request. HD allowed only on devices you can't hack to get the streams. period.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a search on the web, it sounds like a Netflix based issue, which can be solved by checking in your account at http://netflix.com and make sure your stream quality is set to high.

I don't own a Netflix account but people is saying that this option fixes the issue in certain locations as it comes not by default in the settings.

Good luck!

Comment: It is already at the highest quality, but thanks anyways!